# Eclipse says a more recent ADT version is required, but can't find an update

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

In Eclipse I check for available Android packages, at `Window->Android SDK and AVD Manager`.
Under "Available packages" it shows site as `"https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml"` - but underneath there says `"This repository requires a more recent version of ADT. Please update the Eclipse Android plugin"`.

However the "About Eclipse" menu indicates that I am running Android ADT 16.0.1, and when I check for updates with `Help->Check for Updates`, it says `"No updates were found"`.

So how can can I get the Android packages when I require a more recent version of the ADT, but Eclipse says no ADT updates were found?

Regards,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Yury's advice, I uninstalled and re-installed Eclipse. I'm not sure of the previous version, but it was a Helios version at least 2 years old. The new version is Indigo, and now the SDK and AVD managers appear as separate "Window" menu items, and all installed SDK versions appear under SDK manager. I guess there is something about the latest Android stuff that is incompatible with Helios (although the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) claims that Android is compatible with Helios). Thanks Yury!

Comment: Not at all! Mark your answer as a answer for the question (green tick) in order others can find quickly the answer to this question.

Answer (score 17):

I had this problem too when updating from 21.x to 22.

It is not necessary to completely uninstall and re-install Eclipse.

- When eclipse complains about the wrong ADT, simply close the dialog.
- Go to Help/Install new software.
- At "Work with", select "Android Developer Tools Update Site - hxxp://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/"
- Be sure to uncheck "Contact all update sites...". Yes. Uncheck. Why, I don't know, but otherwise it fails. Without explaining why.
- Click on next, confirm license etc., finished.

This worked for me. But the question, why a multi billion dollar project like Android doesn't manage to create a simple and working update without selecting any weird options, is still not answered.

Comment: helped for same problem with 22.6 android developing is a mess

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It says it cannot install it because there is a previous version installed... damn!

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange. If you have installed AVD 16 then you should have separate menu lines for Android SDK Manager and AVD Manager (in Window menu). I think that you should reinstall your eclipse and ADT plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is what I worked in my case, JFTR:

Uninstall ADT:

- Open "About Eclipse" within Help (Linux and Windows) or Eclipse menu (OSX)
- Click on "Installation Details"
- Select only Android Development Tools
- Click "Uninstall"
- After uninstalling Eclipse will ask for restart, so do it.

Reinstall ADT:

- Open "Help/Install new software"
- In "Working with" select the ADT should have an URL like "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/"
- Unfold "Developer Tools" and check only "Android Development Tools"
- Click next and wait for the installation to complete
- Restart Eclipse

I hope it helps someone.