# Android ADT: showing lots of errors

Tags: android, adt

My ADT is versioned 22.3.0 and each time I start up the ADT is shows alert saying that it should be updated to **22.6.2**

However, when I update it, NO UPDATES ARE FOUND.

Also, I cant see any gen folders in my projects.

EDIT::: PFB LOGS:::

> Unable to read repository at
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2/content.xml. Unable to
>   read repository at
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2/content.xml.
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

EDIT :: Please see screenshot after following Gary's idea of unclicking -> contact all sites option.**NOW WHEN I RESTART ,I STILL SEE 22.3 :(** [image]

**EDIT:::ALthough I see the issue but now I am able to build my app and no worries now. Thanks Everyone for the quick info. Closing this question :)**

Comment: Please post errors. Also check this answer for a different version, but similar problem, and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16998818/3593310

Comment: try this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/22524868/1012284

Comment: I honestly recommend you to use Intellij instead of Eclipse for android development. Eclipse is full of bugs and trivial errors and your android project and layouts seem to crash or lose rendering from time to time,

I've been developing android for nearly 3 years and Intellj is definitely my top choice. It's very stable and smooth and their support is great.

Happy Coding !

Comment: @GarySchreiner: Thanks your answer helped but still issue persists.PLease see my update above

Answer (score 1):

I had nearly the same issue `not finding updates`.

For me the problem was solved by re-installing the Android Developer Tools. I don't know why the Update Site was not working anymore even though it was working for months.

Try to go to your `install new software` tab and add

```
Android Developer Tools Update Site - http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

and install the developer tools 'again'. Now, for me, updates are working again.

Or if you prefer you can use the `https://` version also. If one is not working try the other.

Comment: If you see the screenshot in question, the Android `Developer` Tools are at version 22.3 while the Android `Development` Tools are at version 22.6 ???

Comment: For me re-installing manage to put everything in order however I hadn't the 'contact all sites' checked. I re-installed and I let it unchecked. And for me it solved the issue.